# get error on symfony : "Expected argument of type "AppBundle\Entity\Magasin\Caracteristique\ChoixCaracteristique", "string" given"

Tags: symfony

I have a problem with the return code of `ChoiceType` in a form :

```
$form->add('choix',ChoiceType::class, array(
           'choices' => $voila ,
           'multiple'=>false,'label'=>$nom,'expanded'=>true));
```

This code calls the setChoix() function in the entity :

```
public function 
setChoix(\AppBundle\Entity\Magasin\Caracteristique\ChoixCaracteristique 
$choix = null)
{
   $this->choix = $choix;
   return $this;
}
```

Before, I didn't use ChoiceType but EntityType, so, it worked :

```
$form->add('choix', EntityType::class, array(
           'class' => 'AppBundle:Magasin\Caracteristique\ChoixCaracteristique',
           'choices' => $choix,
           'placeholder' => 'Choix',
           'label' => $label,
           'required' => false
        ));
```

My question is"

How to CAST ChoiceType to avoid the problem of type
(EntityType uses `AppBundle:Magasin\Caracteristique\ChoixCaracteristique` type, so it works)

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Why you use ChoiceType for entity ? It's strange. :)

If you want use ChoiceType, you can use DataTransformer for transform choice in `ChoixCaracteristique` entitie after submit : https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html

Comment: Yes I understand :) It's strange to use ChoiceType in form for entity. But you can use DataTransformer for resolve it :)

Comment: ok, thank you very much, but why using EntityType, there's no problem and with ChoiceType, there's a problem .. ?

Comment: EntityType : " A special ChoiceType field that's designed to load options from a Doctrine entity. For example, if you have a Category entity, you could use this field to display a select field of all, or some, of the Category objects from the database. " : https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

With ChoiceType, it's just list or checkbox(s) : string or bool are returned (and your entity is waiting for an `ChoixCaracteristique` class). But you can change ChoiceType return with DataTransformer : https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html

Comment: it means casting ChoiceType by Integer, instead of boolean or string ?

Comment: I'm french too and my english is bad :

1/ Tu as une entité "ChoixCaracteristique". Dans ton formulaire, pour gérer cette entité, il est recommandé d'utiliser `EntityType` qui s'occupe de charger Doctrine. `ChoiceType` ne permet que de gérer des textes (string) ou des booléen.
2/ En liant `ChoiceType` à ton entité `ChoixCaracteristique`, celle-ci retourne une erreur car elle attend un objet `ChoixCaracteristique`
3/ Donc sois tu utilises `EntityType`, sois tu utilises effectivement `ChoiceType` mais il faudra utiliser un DataTransformer, qui transformera le booléen en entité :)

Comment: i found an example (in french ;)  ) !

Answer (score 0):

In my EntityType, I simply added those options:

```
'multiple' => false,
'expanded' => true,
```

To make it work